# req.body.name is not defined - Nodemailer ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, nodemailer

I saw some problems which are close to mine but not exactly the same so my issue is I got a ejs template with a Form attribut and I want to send the input to a mail so I declare all input with name="xyz" and inside the routes.get: `req.body.conSurname, conName: req.body.conName,`. So my post route looks like this.

```
router.post('/contact/send', (req, res) => {
    // Nodemailer
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'abc@gmail.com',
            pass: '******'
        }
    });
    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'abc@gmail.com', 
        to: 'def@gmx.de', 
        subject: 'New Mail', 
        html: '<h2>Mail from: '+ req.body.conSurname + ' ' + conName + '</h2>'
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err)
        else
            console.log(info);
    });
    res.redirect('/contact');
})
```

If I send the formular it throws ReferenceError: conSurname is not defined but if I log one attrubut it shows me the correct value from the input.
Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have to import the json middleware like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.json());
```

Then your express server will deserialize JSON bodies when receiving requests with the `Content-Type: application/json` header, and your code will work correctly.

Comment: Oh okay now it works, I already did this inside the app.js but why I have to do again inside router.js? Do you know

Comment: Well your problem is elsewhere then, you probably declared the json middleware after the router declaration.